# Spark streaming for times series processing (divide data by time interval)

Tags: apache-spark, time-series, spark-streaming

I take flow of data (nginx online log) from UDP socket, data structure is:

```
date                | ip       | mac   | objectName | rate | size
2016-04-05 11:17:34 | 10.0.0.1 | e1:e2 | book1      | 10   | 121
2016-04-05 11:17:34 | 10.0.0.2 | a5:a8 | book2351   | 8    | 2342
2016-04-05 11:17:34 | 10.0.0.3 | d1:b56| bookA5     | 10   | 12

2016-04-05 11:17:35 | 10.0.0.1 | e1:e2 | book67     | 10   | 768
2016-04-05 11:17:35 | 10.0.0.2 | a5:a8 | book2351   | 8    | 897
2016-04-05 11:17:35 | 10.0.0.3 | d1:b56| bookA5     | 9    | 34
2016-04-05 11:17:35 | 10.0.0.4 | c7:c2 | book99     | 9    | 924
...
2016-04-05 11:18:01 | 10.0.0.1 | e1:e2 | book-10    | 8    | 547547
2016-04-05 11:18:17 | 10.0.0.4 | c7:c2 | book99     | 10   | 23423
2016-04-05 11:18:18 | 10.0.0.3 | d1:b56| bookA5     | 10   | 1138
```

I have to:

- Aggregate data, partitioned by minutes - one result row for (minute, ip, mac)
- objectName - can be changed during minute, I have to take the first one, i.e. for `2016-04-05 11:17:34 | 10.0.0.1 | e1:e2` `book1` was changed to `book67`, so must be `book1`
- rate - count of changes rate during munute
- size - difference between sizes (previous time inside partition, current time inside partition), i.e. for `2016-04-05 11:17:34 | 10.0.0.1 | e1:e2` = ... 768 - 121

So, result (without calculation size):

```
date                | ip       | mac   | objectName | changes | size
2016-04-05 11:17:00 | 10.0.0.1 | e1:e2 | book1      | 0       | 768 - 121
2016-04-05 11:17:00 | 10.0.0.2 | a5:a8 | book2351   | 0       | 897 - 2342
2016-04-05 11:17:00 | 10.0.0.3 | d1:b56| bookA5     | 1       | 34 - 12    
2016-04-05 11:17:00 | 10.0.0.4 | c7:c2 | book99     | 0       | 924
...
2016-04-05 11:18:00 | 10.0.0.1 | e1:e2 | book-10    | 0       | 547547
2016-04-05 11:18:00 | 10.0.0.4 | c7:c2 | book99     | 0       | 23423
2016-04-05 11:18:00 | 10.0.0.3 | d1:b56| bookA5     | 0       | 1138
```

Here snap of my code, I know about `updateStateByKey` and about `window` **but I can't understand particularly, how I can flush data to DB or file system, when period (minute) was changed**:

```
private static final Duration SLIDE_INTERVAL = Durations.seconds(10);
private static final String nginxLogHost = "localhost";
private static final int nginxLogPort = 9999;
private class Raw {
  LocalDate time; // full time with seconds
  String ip;
  String mac;
  String objectName;
  int rate;
  int size;
}
private class Key {
  LocalDate time; // time with 00 seconds
  String ip;
  String mac;
}
private class RawValue {
  LocalDate time; // full time with seconds
  String objectName;
  int rate;
  int size;
}
private class Value {
  String objectName;
  int changes;
  int size;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[4]").setAppName("TestNginxLog");
    conf.set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer");
    JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(conf, SLIDE_INTERVAL);
    jssc.checkpoint("/tmp");
JavaReceiverInputDStream<Raw> logRecords = jssc.receiverStream(new NginxUDPReceiver(nginxLogHost, nginxLogPort));
 PairFunction<Raw, Key, RawValue> pairFunction = (PairFunction<Raw, Key, RawValue>) rawLine -> {
        LocalDateTime time = rawLine.getDateTime();
        Key k = new Key(LocalTime.of(time.getHour(), time.getMinute()), rawLine.getIp(), rawLine.getMac());
        RawValue v = new RawValue(time, rawLine.getObjectName(), rawLine.getRate(), rawLine.getSize());
        return new Tuple2<>(k, v);
    };
    JavaPairDStream<Key, RawValue> logDStream = logRecords.mapToPair(pairFunction);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I'm closing this issue by own answer. You can use this function example as the parameter for the `updateStateByKey`. The clue words in this code are: `Optional.absent()` to eliminate the already saved data, `Optional.of(...` to group the data and `setAggregateReady(true)`.
The last one is used for saving the data to an external target (DB or file system) by filter `getAggregateReady(true)` and some of the Spark Streaming output operations, for example, `foreachRDD`.
After that this data in the next batch fall into `updateStateByKey` and will be eliminated by the code `removeIf(T::isAggregateReady)`.

```
/**
 * It aggregates data between batches.
 * <p>
 * currentBatchValues values that was got in current batch
 * previousBatchesState values that was got in all previous batches
 * You have to clear data (return for them Optional.absent()) to eliminate them from DStream.
 * First batch: data checked for aggregateReady.
 * Second batch: data, signed aggregateReady=true removes from DStream (you have to save them to DB or another target before this cleaning)
 */
protected Function2<List<Iterable<T>>, Optional<List<T>>, Optional<List<T>>> updateDataRowsFunc = (currentBatchValues, previousBatchesState) -> {

    Optional<List<T>> res;

    //log.debug("previousBatchesState isPresent {}", previousBatchesState.isPresent());
    //log.debug("previousBatchesState {}", previousBatchesState);
    //log.debug("currentBatchValues isEmpty {}", currentBatchValues.isEmpty());
    //log.debug("currentBatchValues {}", currentBatchValues);

    // previous data that was aggregateReady already saved
    if (previousBatchesState.isPresent()) {
        log.debug("count before remove = {}", previousBatchesState.get().size());
        previousBatchesState.get().removeIf(T::isAggregateReady);
        // absent previous state if all of it's data was aggregated already
        int cntBefore = previousBatchesState.get().size();
        if (cntBefore == 0) previousBatchesState = Optional.absent();
    }

    // warn: can't bear comparator outside, for the reason that error "Task can'not serializable"
    Comparator<T> dataRowByAggGroupComparator = (o1, o2) -> o1.getAggregateGroup().compareTo(o2.getAggregateGroup());

    // no data was collected at previous batches && data exists in current batch
    if (!previousBatchesState.isPresent() && !currentBatchValues.isEmpty()) {

        log.debug("algorithm 1");

        // list currentBatchValues contains only 1 value (1-to-N NginxDataRow records), so we getAllJsonFilesInFolder it Iterable and convert to List
        // warn: may be another way to compare Iterable elements, without using List
        List<T> listDataRow = new ArrayList<>();
        currentBatchValues.get(0).forEach(listDataRow::add);

        // in one batch we can getAllJsonFilesInFolder data for 2 aggregateGroups, if batch was split between groups
        LocalDateTime minAggGroup = listDataRow.stream().min(dataRowByAggGroupComparator).get().getAggregateGroup();
        LocalDateTime maxAggGroup = listDataRow.stream().max(dataRowByAggGroupComparator).get().getAggregateGroup();

        // batch was split between groups
        if (!minAggGroup.equals(maxAggGroup)) {
            log.debug("batch was split between groups {} and {}", minAggGroup, maxAggGroup);
            // set ready to aggregate for previous group of data, because aggregate group was changed
            listDataRow.stream().filter(z -> z.getAggregateGroup().equals(minAggGroup)).forEach(z -> z.setAggregateReady(true));
        }

        res = Optional.of(listDataRow);
        //log.debug("agg res = {}", res);

        // data exist in both: previous and current batches
    } else if (previousBatchesState.isPresent() && !currentBatchValues.isEmpty()) {

        log.debug("algorithm 2");

        List<T> listCurrentBatchDataRow = new ArrayList<>();
        currentBatchValues.get(0).forEach(listCurrentBatchDataRow::add);

        LocalDateTime previousBatchAggGroup = previousBatchesState.get().stream().findFirst().get().getAggregateGroup();

        // in one batch we can getAllJsonFilesInFolder data for 2 aggregateGroups, if batch was split between groups
        LocalDateTime minCurrentBatchAggGroup = listCurrentBatchDataRow.stream().min(dataRowByAggGroupComparator).get().getAggregateGroup();
        LocalDateTime maxCurrentBatchAggGroup = listCurrentBatchDataRow.stream().max(dataRowByAggGroupComparator).get().getAggregateGroup();

        // previous and current data in different groups
        if (!previousBatchAggGroup.equals(maxCurrentBatchAggGroup)) {

            log.debug("previous batch needed to save, because agg group was changed from {} to {}", previousBatchAggGroup, maxCurrentBatchAggGroup);
            // set ready to aggregate for previous group of data, because aggregate group was changed
            previousBatchesState.get().stream().forEach(z -> z.setAggregateReady(true));

            // batch was split between groups
            if (!minCurrentBatchAggGroup.equals(maxCurrentBatchAggGroup)) {

                log.debug("batch was split between groups {} and {}", minCurrentBatchAggGroup, maxCurrentBatchAggGroup);
                listCurrentBatchDataRow.stream().filter(z -> z.getAggregateGroup().equals(minCurrentBatchAggGroup)).forEach(z -> z.setAggregateReady(true));

            }
        }

        // union previous and current batches data
        previousBatchesState.get().addAll(listCurrentBatchDataRow);

        res = Optional.of(previousBatchesState.get());
        //log.debug("agg res = {}", res);

        // data exist in previous batch but current batch is empty
    } else if (previousBatchesState.isPresent() && currentBatchValues.isEmpty()) {

        log.debug("algorithm 3");

        res = previousBatchesState;
        //log.debug("agg res = {}", res);

        // all of previous data was aggregated and absent() already
    } else if (!previousBatchesState.isPresent() && currentBatchValues.isEmpty()) {

        log.debug("algorithm 4");

        res = Optional.absent();

    } else {

        log.error("Strange situation, you have to check log-file");
        res = null;

    }

    // if abonent data was received in one minute and after abonent shut down connection, they will stay in DStream forever
    // after some period forced to save them
    if (res != null && res.isPresent()) {
        res.get().stream().filter(z -> Math.abs(java.time.Duration.between(z.getAggregateGroup(), LocalDateTime.now()).getSeconds() / 60) > FORCED_SAVE_INTERVAL).forEach(z -> z.setAggregateReady(true));
    }

    return res;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is **partial answer**, but question not finished already. After `mapToPair` I use:

```
    // 1 key - N values
    JavaPairDStream<Key, Iterable<Value>> abonentConnects = logDStream.groupByKey();

    // Accumulate data
    Function2<List<Iterable<Value>>, Optional<List<Value>>, Optional<List<Value>>> updateFunc = (Function2<List<Iterable<Value>>, Optional<List<Value>>, Optional<List<Value>>>) (values, previousState) -> {
        List<Value> sum = previousState.or(new ArrayList<>());
        for (Iterable<Value> v : values) {
            v.forEach(sum::add);
        }
        return Optional.of(sum);
    };
    JavaPairDStream<Key, List<Value>> state = abonentConnects.updateStateByKey(updateFunc);

    // filter data (previous minute)
    Function<Tuple2<Key, List<Value>>, Boolean> filterFunc = (Function<Tuple2<Key, List<Value>>, Boolean>) v1 -> {
        LocalDateTime previousTime = LocalDateTime.now().minusMinutes(1).withSecond(0).withNano(0);
        LocalDateTime valueTime = v1._1().getTime();
        return valueTime.compareTo(previousTime) == 0;
    };
    JavaPairDStream<Key, List<Value>> filteredRecords = state.filter(filterFunc);

    // save data
    filteredRecords.foreachRDD(x -> {
        if (x.count() > 0) {
            x.saveAsTextFile("/tmp/xxx/grouped/" + LocalDateTime.now().toString().replace(":", "-").replace(".", "-"));
        }
    });

    streamingContext.start();
    streamingContext.awaitTermination();
```

As result data produce, but since operations executed every 5 seconds, I getting the same duplicated data every 5 second of a minute.
I know, that I have to use `Optional.absent()` for clear saved data from streaming. I've tried to use it, but I can't combine in one fragment: save data to file system or HashMap | clear saved data immediately.
**Question**: how I can do it?